# Return dropdown string from second table

Tags: entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have two tables I need to join for my Razor Page view.  The first table called 'Account' contains an Account record with a int Status.  The second table called 'AccountStatuses' contains possible statuses for the Account.  Scaffolding created the following code in Account\Index.cshtml.cs

```
    public IList<Account> Account { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Account = await _context.Account.ToListAsync();
    }
```

The Account table contains a column "Status" that corresponds to the column "Value" in the AccountStatus table.  I want to join on these and return the column "StatusString" from the AccountStatus table to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to join the two tables to get the values. If you setup properly your models you can let Entity Framework do the work for you. I will give you an example of how I would create the models. First of all, we have the two models:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public int AccountStatusID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountStatusID")]
    public virtual AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
}


public class AccountStatus
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountStatusID { get; set; }

    public string AccountStatusName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

The Account model has the property AccountStatusID which will contain the id for the status. We also define a virtual property for the AccountStatus model. This will be automatically loaded by EntityFramework for us when we ask it from Entity Framework.

We do something similar for the AccountStatus model but in this model we will have a virtual collection of Account models.

Now we will have to define our ApplicationDbContext class which could be the following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountStatus> AccountStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can execute the following queries:

```
// Get the account by id
Account account1 = await _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AccountID == id);

// Get the account by id including the Account status
Account account2 = await _context.Accounts.Include(m => m.AccountStatus).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AccountID == id);
// account2.AccountStatus contains the AccountStatus
string AccountStatusName = account2.AccountStatus.AccountStatusName;


// Get teh account status by id
AccountStatus AccountStatus1 = await _context.AccountStatuses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AccountStatusID == id);

// Get the account status by id include the accounts
AccountStatus AccountStatus2 = await _context.AccountStatuses.Include(m => m.Accounts).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AccountStatusID == id);
// AccountStatus2.Accounts contain all the accounts which has be set to be equal to the current account status
foreach (var account in AccountStatus2.Accounts)
{
    string AccountName = account.AccountName;
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  I have a few questions for your solution.  What is the need for " public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }" in the AccountStatus model?  Since this is a dropdown option table I don't see much use in the AccountStatus model referencing Accounts.

Comment: What you have here is a one to many relationship. You may not need this reference now but usually we want to get the list from an object or get the object for each element of the list. The models that I created will generate the one to many relationship in database and you will be able to access both ways your data. This will not affect the performance of your query if you do not use the include method but on the other hand it will give you the ability easily to ask extra information in case you need them.